# Jquery how to get change event in the element later loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

The rows of my table are added dynamically and within each row possess a select option, I need to perform an action when the select is changed, but because the line is loaded after the page loaded, my function does not work.

```
<table id="grid-items" class="table table-bordered table-hover">        
<thead>             
    <th>Cod</th>
    <th>Desc</th>
    <th>Uni</th>        
    <th>N.C.M.</th>                                                                         
</thead>            
<tr>                                
    <td><input type="text" id=""  class="form-control item-cod" required></input></td>                                      
    <td style="width:400px;"><select data-placeholder="Selecione" class="chosen-select item-descricao" style="width:350px;"  tabindex="2" id=""></select></td>
    <td><input type="text"  id=""  class="form-control item-ncm" required></input></td>                             
    <td><button class="btn btn-default bg-red" onclick="RemoveTableRow(this)" type="button">Remover</button></td>
</tr>   
<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5" style="text-align: left;">
           <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="AddTableRow()" type="button">Adicionar Item</button>
        <td>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
```

My function to add row

```
function AddTableRow() {



var newRow = $("<tr>");
var cols = "";

cols += '<td><input type="text" id="item-codigo" name="produto.itens[].codigo" class="form-control" required></input></td>';
cols += '<td style="width:400px;"><select data-placeholder="Selecione" class="chosen-select item-descricao" style="width:350px;"  tabindex="2" id=""></select></td>';

cols += '<td><input type="text" id="item-ncm" name="produto.itens[].ncm" class="form-control" required></input></td>';     

cols += '<td>';
cols += '<button class="btn btn-default bg-red" onclick="RemoveTableRow(this)" type="button">Remover</button>';
cols += '</td>';        

newRow.append(cols);
$("#grid-items").append(newRow);


var options = '<option value="">Selecione</option>';

$.each(produtos, function (key, val){
    options += '<option value="' + val.id + '">' + val.descricao + '</option>';
});

$("td .item-descricao").html(options);

var config = {
          '.chosen-select'           : {},
          '.chosen-select-deselect'  : {allow_single_deselect:true},
          '.chosen-select-no-single' : {disable_search_threshold:10},
          '.chosen-select-no-results': {no_results_text:'Oops, nothing found!'},
          '.chosen-select-width'     : {width:"95%"}
        }



for (var selector in config) {
    $(selector).chosen(config[selector]);
}
```

Whem change select:

```
$("td .item-descricao").on("change", function(e) {


var codigo = this.value;

$.each(produtos, function (key, val){

        if( val.id == codigo){          



            $("td .item-codigo").val(val.id).trigger('change');
            $("td .item-ncm").val(val.ncm).trigger('change');
        }           

    });
```

});

which function could use to manipulate the dynamic selects? Tks.

Comment: By "does not work", do you mean the event isn't triggered?  Or is the event triggered but the result is not what you expect?

Comment: @devlincarnate the event isn't triggered

Comment: I've edited my added answer to add a concrete code example in your context. Please, give it a try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can delegate the event to a parent element:

```
$("parent-selector-goes-here").on("change", "child-selector-goes-here", function(e) {
    // your code for the items' events
    // here, "this" will be the event target element
};
```

In your case:

```
$("#grid-items").on("chage", "td .item-descricao", function(e) {
    var codigo = this.value;

    $.each(produtos, function (key, val) {
        if (val.id == codigo) {
            $("td .item-codigo").val(val.id).trigger('change');
            $("td .item-ncm").val(val.ncm).trigger('change');
        }
    });
});
```

--
Boa sorte! ;)

Comment: It's nice to see a generic pattern for solving the problem, but this answer would be more helpful if you also gave an example of the specific implementation, since the OP has provided the HTML.

Comment: You are completely right, but I'm on a mobile browser and coding in a touch screen is not really a pleasure.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you're right, this line will take the currently matched elements and attach the change event:

```
$("td .item-descricao").on("change", function(e)  { ... });
```

What you should use instead is attach the event handler on the document, and filter it to trigger the event only if it matches the CSS selector:

```
$(document).on("change", "td .item-descricao", function(e)  { 
var target = $(e.target);
// ...
 });
```

The reason why this works is called "event bubbling": The change event will "bubble up" the DOM tree, so coming from the select all the way up to the html-Tag and above this, there is the document as parent of all tags.